# Python regex select numbers selectively with re.findall( r'( )', string)

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract only the text part and sub number in the end of the strings, from:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor?::enim',
'9. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem.2',
'. . . . . 9.1 dolore magnam aliquam quaerat',
'. . . . . 9.1 ed quia consequuntur magni.1',
'. . . . . 9.2 Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2'
```

like this:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor?::enim',
'Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem.2',
'dolore magnam aliquam quaerat',
'ed quia consequuntur magni.1',
'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2'
```

Is it possible do that with single re.findall(r'( )', item) in python regex? 
Seems like I'm not able to 'separate' the numbers in the beginning of the string from the number in the end on of the string.

I've tried for example with following code:

```
string ='. . . . . 9.2 Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2' 
string = re.findall(r'([a-öA-Ö0-9/:._]+)',string)
string = ' '.join( list(filter(lambda x: x != '.', string)))
```

This gives:

```
'9.2 Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2'
```

But this doesn't remove the number in front, is complex and also splits the original text and joins back with space in between. I would like to cut the string where the text starts and don't want to touch the original text part really, there could be for example two spaces between words sometime, but those should be preserved as is.

Comment: Can you show the regex you've tried so far? Thanks.

Comment: @mpeli you should include in your question an attempt at the regex and what's wrong with it.  You'll get better responses if you can do this.  I'll throw out an attempt to help but I shouldn't really. https://regex101.com/r/L6D8Dp/1

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @MDR Thank you, works well. Doesn't seem obvious to me but I'll study it.

Comment: Regex is complete gobbledygook until you take some time to study the syntax ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert substrings that match the regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag set)

```
(?<=^')[^a-z]+
```

to empty strings.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TwP3XV/1/)

The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters other than letters that follow a single quote at the beginning of a line", `(?<=^')` being a *positive lookbehind*.

Comment: Thanks, this works as I want in regex101, but in python I can't get it to work. A pity because this is the simplest proposal to me by this far. 
string = '. . . . . 9.2 Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2' 
result = re.findall(r"(?<=^)[^a-z]+", string, flags=re.IGNORECASE) gives 
result = ['. . . . . 9.2 '] , this is exactly the part I don't need.  
If i have result = re.findall(r"(?<=^')[^a-z]+", string, flags=re.IGNORECASE) , I get 
result = [ ]. That little ' is the only difference

Comment: mpeli, I thought my Python code [here](http://tpcg.io/vaJjtrsZ) should work but the fact that it doesn't must reflect on my near-zero knowledge of Python rather than the regex itself. You can see at the link in my answer that matches of the regex I gave, when replaced with empty strings, provides the desired result. Moreover, in Ruby, `str.gsub(/(?<=^)[^a-z]+/, '')` gives the correct result. Perhaps you or another reader can spot an error in my Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a more complex regular expression, for example:

```
import re

expression = re.compile(r'(.*?[0-9].+? )*(.+)')

# this is a list of tuples, and you are always interested in the last match
results = expression.findall('<string>')[-1][-1]
```

Comment: Thanks this works too, although I need to study how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

```
import re

text = """
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor?::enim',
'9. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem.2',
'. . . . . 9.1 dolore magnam aliquam quaerat',
'. . . . . 9.1 ed quia consequuntur magni.1',
'. . . . . 9.2 Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2'
"""

pattern = re.compile(r".*?(\d\.\d? )")

print(pattern.sub(r"'", text))
```

Outputs:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor?::enim',
'Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem.2',
'dolore magnam aliquam quaerat',
'ed quia consequuntur magni.1',
'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit.2'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works also. Overall the re 'spell' looks simpler here, not sure what sub( r" ' ", ) does exactly,  why ' has to be there, guess comes from some deep syntax...